# Set 2 hours to end time date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

My first time ever trying to edit some objective-c.

I'm trying to edit the phonegap calendar plugin that will add dates into the iPhone calendar but as my dates don't have an end time and I want to edit it so that it will automatically sets the endtime **2 hours after the start time**:

```
NSString* title      = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
NSString* location   = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
NSString* message    = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *startDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];
//NSString *endDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:5];

//creating the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter *sDate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[sDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myStartDate = [sDate dateFromString:startDate];

//NSDateFormatter *eDate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//[eDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//NSDate *myEndDate = [eDate dateFromString:endDate];
NSDate *myEndDate = [myStartDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:  2*60*60];

myEvent.title = title;
myEvent.location = location;
myEvent.notes = message;
myEvent.startDate = myStartDate;
myEvent.endDate = myEndDate;
myEvent.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
```

I'm not getting any errors but when I test my app, it doesn't add the date into the calendar anymore.

Comment: ur codes seems correct. the thing is to check make sure  u r getting value in myStartDate